Existence of solutions PDE
Consider the following partial differential equation for some function $f(x,y) \neq 0$:
\begin{equation}
9\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}.
\end{equation}
Does this equation has some simple evident solutions or not?

Well, evidently, if $f=a$ for some arbitrarily chosen constant $a$, the equation holds. What have you tried to solve the equation?

Tried some solutions indeed. It appears in my research in physics, I am not a mathematician, hence my question. If there is some solution evident that is not constant, it would already be interesting for me. The constant situation would be just de Sitter in this context. I would like less trivial solutions. An exponential of something or that sort.

You’re asking about the existence of solutions or examples of nontrivial solutions?

$f(x,y)=g(x)$ or $f(x,y)=h(y)$ works for any sufficiently regular $g$ and $h$

Ansatz: $f(x,y) = g(x+y)$.
Then $f$ solves the PDE $\iff 9 (g')^2 = \frac{g''}{g} \iff 9g(g')^2 = g''$.
Let $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $c \neq 0$ and $g(t) := \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\text{erf}^{-1}(ct+d)$ for $|ct+d| < 1$.
Let $h(t) := \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}g(t)$. Then It holds $\text{erf}\left(h(t)\right) = ct+d$. It follows that
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}h'(t)e^{-h^2(t)} = \left(\text{erf}\left(h(t)\right)\right)' = (ct+d)' = c$$
Thus $$h' = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}ce^{h^2}$$
and therefore
$$h'' = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}ce^{h^2}\right)' = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}c 2hh'e^{h^2} =  2hh'\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}ce^{h^2}\right) = 2h(h')^2.$$
It follows
$$9g(g')^2 = 9\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}h\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}h'\right)^2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\cdot2h(h')^2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}h'' = g''.$$
Thus let
$$f(x,y) := g(x+y) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\text{erf}^{-1}(c(x+y)+d)$$ with
$(x,y) \in D:= \{(x',y') \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ 0 < |c(x+y)+d| < 1 \}$. Then by the above $f$ solves the PDE.
